# Pipleline adds a job in schedule which is set to not run in schedule

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have added workflow rules and rules at the job level. I have two jobs, one of them is set to run on schedule and also when the Pipeline source is 'web'. The other job is set to run for merge request events, and when a commit is pushed to default branch, and when Pipeline source is 'web'(when a Pipeline is initiated by user).

Workflow rules that I have set in Pipeline are:

workflow:

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE =~ /^(schedule|web)$/
```

Job rules for test_job & test_job_parallel:

test_job:

```
  variables:
    WHICH_ENVIRONMENT: dev0
    WHICH_TAG: '@V3'
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "$WHICH_ENVIRONMENT"
    - echo "$WHICH_TAG"
    - ./gradlew clean test "-Dkarate.env=$WHICH_ENVIRONMENT" "-Dkarate.options=--tags  $WHICH_TAG"
        
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" && $PARALLEL == "false"
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
      when: never
```

test_job_parallel:

```
  variables:
    WHICH_TAG: '@V3'
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "$ENVIRONMENT"
    - echo "$WHICH_TAG"
    - ./gradlew clean test "-Dkarate.env=$ENVIRONMENT" "-Dkarate.options=--tags $WHICH_TAG"
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ENVIRONMENT: ['dev0', 'dev1', 'itest']

  rules:
    - if: ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE =~ /^(schedule|web)$/) && $PARALLEL == "true"
```

#Note: PARALLEL is a global variable with default value "false"

As we can see, in first job, I did use a rule to avoid adding the test_job to pipeline when the pipeline source is 'schedule'. But, this job gets added to schedule when the schedule is ran for default branch (master) and the rule works as expected if the schedule was ran on a feature branch.
The schedule is meant to run parallel job which runs tests on all environments. And, I passed variable PARALLEL value 'true' when I created a schedule on master branch.

But, the schedule picks both the jobs when it was ran on master branch (which is CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH)
How do I avoid running test_job in Pipeline when the schedule is set to run on master branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of rules matters. Only the first matching rule takes effect. Move your `when: never` rule(s) to the top of the list. Otherwise, any rule that matches before it will take precedence.

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" && $PARALLEL == "false"
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've made changes to the order of rules & its working as expected in schedule. But, this is causing a duplicate pipeline when I trigger it manually by passing PARALLEL to true. I see test_job along with test_job_parallel in Pipeline even though I have added rule for test_job to run only when PARALLEL is set to false.

Comment: @sivaji hmm. I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean. But maybe you just need another rule like `if: $PARALLEL != "true"; when: never` If you can't figure it out after reviewing the `rules:` configuration and documentation for `parallel:matrix` maybe consider opening a new question.

Comment: I thought the same, to add - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" && $PARALLEL != "true" to 'test_job'. I'll try and see if it works or not.